# AWS Cloudfront signed url access denied for folder

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

1. In S3 I have zip file "file.zip" and decompressed folder "file.zip/"
2. I have CloudFront Distribution with origin like "bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com" (also tried without region)
3. I generate CloudFront signed URL for both resources with .NET AWSSDK

```
url = AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.GetCustomSignedURL(
    AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.Protocol.https,
    _cloudFrontConfiguration.CloudFrontDistributionDomain,
    privateKey: reader,
    resourcePath,
    _cloudFrontConfiguration.CloudFrontKeyPairId,
    expiresAt,
    ipRange: null);
```

4. Link for file looks like 'https://...cloudfront.net/...pathInBucket/file.zip?...params', for folder 'https://...cloudfront.net/...pathInBucket/file.zip/?...params'
5. I can download zip file by link, but for the folder, I got '403 access denied'

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

S3 does not really have folders. Therefore, you cannot "download a folder". What you can do is list a specific prefix (folder) and download all the objects, under that prefix. See also official [documentation on this topic](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-prefix-nested-folders-difference/).

> In Amazon S3, folders are used to group objects and organize files. Unlike a traditional file system, Amazon S3
> doesn't use hierarchy to organize its objects and files. For the sake
> of organizational simplicity, Amazon S3 console supports the folder
> concept as a means of grouping objects.

Moreover, you are getting 403, because your signed URL is invalid as it is probably pointing to a nonexistent object. For example, the base URL ends with a prefix (`/foldername/`)instead with an object (`/foldername/someobject`).

Best, Stefan

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution:

1. Generate signed url for resource string "file.zip/*". Result string looks like "https://distribution.../file.zip/*?Policy=..."
2. Use signed url query parameters (or set cookies) from step 1 to get resources from folder like "https://distribution.../file.zip/file1.txt?Policy=..."

Every resource in folder is accessible with query parameters from step 1. Folder structure may be a question, but for me it wasn't necessary.